# Unable to find the runtime directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

In advance, apologies for any improperly used terminology... I'm fairly new to web development/hosting, and IIS

I am trying to host a 64 bit ASP.Net 5 (MVC 6) web application, which uses beta 7, via IIS 7.5 on a windows Server 2008 R2 Standard machine.

I am publishing from Visual Studio 2015 (on a Windows 8 laptop) to a shared folder on the server. My IIS web application's physical path is the wwwroot folder created in the publish directory and the website seems to *attempt* to launch correctly...

Whenever the site attempts to run, however, I receive an error which states the following:

> Unable to find the runtime directory 'D:\www\mysite\wwwroot\..\approot\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7'
>
> Possible causes:
>
> 1. The runtime was not packaged with the application
> 2. The packaged runtime architecture is different from the application pool architecture.

The frustrating part is that if I copy and paste the link IIS claims it can't find and paste it into Windows Explorer, it leads me to a directory which **does** exist. That rules out the first explanation. As far as the second explanation goes, I have checked my publishing profile in Visual Studio and ensured that it is indeed the 64bit version of beta 7.

As far as I can tell, the proper runtime *is* sent with the published files, and they are the correct versions.

Is there anything I'm missing? The application runs fine in Visual Studio 2015. I don't know why when running on IIS it can't find a folder which not only exists, but is readily available to be browsed to.

**UPDATE:** I've continued to fight with this problem and found some odd symptoms... I can successfully make a website application from just about *anywhere* other than the D:\www folder. I stuck my site's published files container directly into the D drive and made a site directly from that, and it launched without a hitch. I was also able to replicate this on the C drive, and even placed the published files container into a folder called "wwww" in the D drive (so its physical path was D:\wwww\MySite\wwwroot as opposed to D:\www\MySite\wwwroot).

Does anybody know why "www" is problematic in particular? The folder structure in place here has several other (albeit much older) websites running from the www folder, so it's ideal that this application is placed in the same area. It seems like it works everywhere *but* there, however.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could be a rights issue.  The apppool user often doesn't have rights to folders it needs, especially when they're in strange locations like the D drive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, James. The app pool doesn't seem to be having much trouble accessing anything from what I can see. I updated my post with what I've found out; it seems to be the name of the parent folder causing the trouble so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, the solution I went with was to not place the application's publish folder in the D:\www folder. I ended up simply creating another folder in the root of the D drive and pointing the web application in IIS to that.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible causes might be insufficient permissions for IIS user.

I added permission for `approot` (runtime) folder for `IIS_IUSRS` to read. Looks like IIS user was unable to read and load content of this directory because of insufficient permissions. After that it worked fine.